# Harry Potter fan fiction with a rune that turns things to sand

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Harry discovers he has magic at a young age. He snaps and kills the Dursleys due to his ill-treatment. He is then sent to a correctional facility, where Dumbledore finds him and enrols him into Hogwarts.

Harry has no friends, except for Hermione who couldn't leave him alone. Harry is fascinated by runes. He searches for a rune that can turn anything to sand. He is drawn towards the desert rune.

This is an unfinished fan fic, maybe even on hiatus. It's pretty lengthy, with at least 80k words, without romance/pairings. Fits into insane Harry/horror/supernatural categories.

Comment: Do you possibly remember what site you read it on?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is [Worthy of Magic](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12800980/1/Worthy-of-Magic), by Sage Ra, published on FanFiction.net.

> **Harry discovers he has magic at a young age. He snaps and kills the  Dursleys due to his ill-treatment.**

In Part 1, "The Void", Harry murders the Dursleys after being punished for beating Dudley in a maths test:

> "Hi," he said. "My Aunt and Uncle are dead, if you came looking for them. It felt re~ally good killing them." It was the longest sentence Harry had ever spoken.

---

> **He is then sent to a correctional facility, where Dumbledore finds him
>   and enrols him into Hogwarts.**

In Part 2, "Convicted", Harry is at the Janus Home for Criminal Children, and meets Dumbledore for the first time.

> Harry had fallen into a comfortable routine at The Janus Home for Criminal Children. [...] Today was a strange day for Harry. His routine had been broken.
>   Instead of meeting Beverly and giving her the silent treatment, he was
>   to meet a Professor from a school for the gifted. [...] "You have a
>   place in my school Harry. Your parents, who were a witch and wizard by
>   the way, enrolled your name when your were three months old. It will
>   be your home for seven years, until you're ready to join the magical
>   world as an adult."

---

> **Harry has no friends, except for Hermione who couldn't leave him alone.**

In Part 4, "Hogwarts", Harry avoids making friends, but Hermione is insistent.

> They tried to befriend him. They tried to talk to him. [...] Learning
>   about magic was all he cared about. [...] "What do you want?" Harry
>   asked with disinterest. [...] "To be friends," she said firmly. Harry
>   blinked. She had been persistent because she wanted to be friends?
>   "Friends?" Harry echoed strangely. It was an entirely foreign concept
>   to him...

---

> **Harry is fascinated by runes. He searches for a rune that can turn
>   anything to sand. He is drawn towards the desert rune.**

Runes seem to be mentioned quite a lot throughout, as well as deserts - for example, in Part 24, "Two Problems", there's specific mention of the desert rune.

> **This is an unfinished fan fic, maybe even on hiatus.**

I glanced through the last one but without reading the whole thing, I couldn't tell you if it counted as an ending or not, so I'll leave that one for you!

> **It's pretty lengthy, with at least 80k words, without romance/pairings.**

There are 57 parts on FanFiction.net, it's now at 147K words. I can't tell if there's any romance, but there are none mentioned in the summary or tags.

> **Fits into insane Harry/horror/supernatural categories.**

Category on FanFiction.net is Horror/Adventure.

Comment: FYI you can access a raw HTML of the page with CTRL+U and copy-paste the text from here, or use the browser inspector (CTRL+Shift+I) and hover over the paragraphs to access the text. Truly disabling copy-pasting is borderline impossible. (it seems to be a good find anyway, +1)

Comment: @Jenayah Heh, you're right, I was being a bit lazy. I'll look at finding some quotes.

Comment: "Your parents, who were a witch and wizard by the way." Classic!

Answer (score 2):

"[Control](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5866937/1/Control)"

> I'm sick of the manipulation, the lies and the deceit; sick of jumping to the tune of dark lords and old puppeteers. I'm cutting the strings. Innocents will pay in blood for my defiance, but I no longer care. I lost my innocence long ago. Dark!Harry

"[The Denarian Renegade](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/3473224/1/The-Denarian-Renegade)"

> By the age of seven, Harry Potter hated his home, his relatives and his life. However, an ancient demonic artefact has granted him the powers of a Fallen and now he will let nothing stop him in his quest for power. AU: Slight Xover with Dresden Files

These are Probably what you are looking for.

Comment: As it stands, this is a link-only answer. Could you edit your answer to explain why you believe these fanfictions match the OP's description?

Comment: Do either of these include the sand rune? I'm pretty positive the Denarian Renegade doesn't.